# spinner inside button has incorrect color

Tags: angular, angular-material, theming

When I add a `mat-spinner` to a button

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent">
    <mat-spinner color="primary">
    </mat-spinner> Accent
</button>
```

[image]

I cannot align the color with the text color of that button. Is there any way I can give the spinner the same color as the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers given show that it cannot be done with the components itself. The problem with the given answers is that when you change your theme, you also have fix these colours. For example, if the button is disabled, the color should be grey.

To have the spinner in the right color I created the following global css

```
.spinner-button {
    circle {
        stroke: currentColor; 
    }
}
```

This way, the stroke color comes from the parent, which is the button and aligns with the current theme :)

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbkkbb?file=src%2Fstyles.scss)

[Improved demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-spinnerr-button?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since Angular Material components only allows `primary`, `accent` or `warn` you need to solve this by using CSS.

Give the spinner a class:

```html
  <mat-spinner class="my-spinner">
  </mat-spinner> Accent
```

And in your global css:

```css
  .my-spinner.mat-spinner circle {
    stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); // change to the color you want
  }
```

Defining the css in your component styles will not work unless you change the [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation)

Answer (score 1):

Angular has a deep protocol for css. In your css file just add

```css
/deep/ mat-spinner circle {
  stroke: white
}
```